# Создайние файлов в Visual C# 2010

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите как мне сделать так чтобы при запуске программы, создавалось 255 файлов конфига с параметрами?

```
[MapSize] = 30;
[StartX] = 14;
[StartY] = 20;
[MapName] = "TestMap"
```

И таких 255? Я смог сделать это для ListBox'a, но вот чтобы **СОЗДАТЬ** такие файлы, я не знаю как.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string mapper = "karta";
        const string namer = ".map";
        for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(mapper + i + namer);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines
System.IO.FileStream` (посложнее, но эффективнее)

Comment: Я не совсем понял, как их использовать...

Answer (score 1):

Например [File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d62kzs03.aspx)

UPD:
а вообще ваша задача похожа больше на сериализацию неких 255 элементов настроек. Это позволит иметь простой объектный доступ в обе стороны к данным в файлах.

UPD2: создайте сущность для хранения одного конфига, например:

```
public class Config
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Далее создайте все нужные объекты с данными и загоните их в *List<Config>*, после чего просто сериализируйте данный список в любом формате в файл. После этого вы сможете десериализировать в любой момент эти данные и обращаться к каждому, как к элементу списка. Мне кажется - это оптимальный способ с минимальным кодом.

Comment: Ну да я хочу сделать 255 карт, и конфиги к каждой из них.

Comment: Да а как реализовать чтобы создались как в цикле... 255(каждый раз номер увеличивался на 1), и чтобы прога автоматов, записывала в каждый файл:

    [MapSize] = 30;
    [StartX] = 14;
    [StartY] = 20;
    [MapName] = "TestMap"

Comment: Ну по примеру из мсдн, что я дал можно записать в файлы что угодно. Как вы собираетесь после с ними работать? И обязателен ли данный формат?

Comment: Формат необязателен, мне просто нужны конфиги... я хочу сделать конструктор РПГ...нужен редиктор карт, который будет считывать все что в karta[номер карты]..